# Как запустить Laravel из внешнего php скрипта?

Tags: php, laravel

Было написано консольное приложения на Laravel 5.4 для определённой задачи.
Запускалось оно по принцепу:

```
php artisan {command}
```

Но мне поставили задачу чтоб запускалось приложения из внешнего php файла, как это сделать не используя exec(), точку входа через HTTP? 
(Должно выглядит как composer пакет (вся логика в app)).
(идея не моя)

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/artisan ;)

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить такое решение:

```
<?php
require 'путь_до_папки_проекта_на_laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php';
Artisan::call(команда);
```